# Know Tokbox video resolution on JS side

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

With a `session ID` and `Tokbox` Inspector Redirect tool we can see how the publisher scales up and down video resolution while trying to adapt to the bandwidth available.

It is possible to know this video size from `javascript`?

It would be handy to let users know that video streaming quality is poor because connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

Using the JavaScript client SDK you have a couple things available to you:

First, on the [`Publisher`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#getStats) and [`Subscriber`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getStats), you can call `getStats(completionHandler)` which will give you:

- The total number of audio and video packets lost
- The total number of audio and video packets sent
- The total number of audio and video bytes sent
- The current video frame rate

Secondly, on the session you can subscribe to the sessions [`streamPropertyChanged`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/StreamPropertyChangedEvent.html) event to identify when a stream has started or stopped publishing audio or video, when the video dimensions have changed or when the video type has changed.

Comment: Thanks! this is what we need.

Comment: Thank you! I found that when archiving mobile users videos (vertical) it records landscape videos with wide black frames on sides (publisher options are 1280x720). Is it possible to record it in original resolution or in any vertical ratio if all my users are on mobiles always?